# res.send(), then res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, express

Why is the following not working?

```
res.send({
    successMessage: 'Task saved successfully.'
});
res.redirect('/');
```

I basically need the successMessage for AJAX requests. The redirect is necessary when the request is a standard post request (non-AJAX).

The following approach doesn't seem to be very clean to me as I don't want to care about the frontend-technology in my backend:

```
if(req.xhr) {
    res.contentType('json');
    res.send({
        successMessage: 'Aufgabe erfolgreich gespeichert.'
    });
} else {
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a status code to indicate that your task was saved and then redirect. Try this:

```
res.status(200);
res.redirect('/');
```

OR

```
res.redirect(200, '/');
```

Because AJAX knows success or failure codes, so for example if you'll send 404, AJAX success function won't execute

Comment: What if you want to send data to your app in a redirect?

Comment: make an ajax request to the server when the redirected page loads.

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet doesn't work because `res.send` sends headers already, so the `res.redirect` after that simply impossible.

The second snippet should work. Basically, what it does is a check if the request is AJAX (then returns JSON), otherwise redirection takes place.

Comment: But is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: Sure, separate your JSON API from serving HTML pages.