# Nodejs / Express Redirect after POST

Tags: express, payment-gateway

I'm trying to rebuild an app based from PHP to MEAN and I've tried integrating a 3rd party payment gateway where users can enter their credit card info.

I was able to create a post request using the ['request' module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and received a response status code 200 from the third party. Now that the request is fulfilled is there a way to redirect the user to the third party's site (similar to a POST request done with html forms and PHP)?

Here's the code block of the post request

```
function(req, res) {
request({
    url: 'https://urlopaymentgateway',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    form:data,
    followAllRedirects:true
},function(error,response,body){
    if(error) {
        console.log("FAIL");
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        /* How to do redirection here? */
    }
});
}
```

After further reading, the `followAllRedirects` work only if the status code is between 300 and 400.

Comment: possible duplicate of [res.send(), then res.redirect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439526/res-send-then-res-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to node, but this works for me.

```
router.post('/some_path/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('<html><body></body><script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/some_new_path";</script></html>');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make redirects via `res.redirect()`, http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect

Also, you may want to get redirected url from your POST request, here is it

```
  function(error,response,body){
    if(error) {
        console.log("FAIL");
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        var url = response.request.href
        res.redirect(url)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @vmkcom, for your reply. I tried this one too, the `url` is correct, but the redirect won't push through.

Comment: `res.redirect` no working? Try to check via `curl` what status code are sent, and check how do you sent request (via ajax for example). Express only sent status code 30x for redirect