# Express JS res.send() then res.redirect

Tags: node.js, express

Any pointers?

My head is against a brick wall.

My server needs to know the javascript on the client side and redirects the user after some calculations are done.
Here's step by step what I'm trying to do :)

1. Client connects to site
2. Server delivers html with javascript that returns some info about the client's browser ie window.width
3. Server retrieves information
4. Server checks some criteria with the information
5. Server redirects client to the appropriate ip address

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Thrown at end of code: `res.redirect('192.168.1.254')`

```
//Send javascript to client
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(`
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var info = {
            clientwidth: 'test',
            clientheight: 'test',
            clientspeed: 'test'
            };
        var objectData = JSON.stringify(info);
        $.post('/', { clientInfo: objectData });
        }
    </script>
    `)
    return next()
});

// Read javascript object clientInfo
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let clientInfo = req.body.clientInfo;
    res.json({ok: true});
    console.log('Client connected: ' + clientInfo);
    return next()
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('192.168.1.254')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So, It's not possible to res.send() and then res.redirect(). Your return next() is pushing the code to be executed at the next middleware.

Your first get method and second get method are conflicting because both have a response. You can only make one response to the client.

Check this: [res.send(), then res.redirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439526/res-send-then-res-redirect)

Update:

Check the code below. This may be helpful for the flow you've mentioned. (check the comments for reference to steps & details)

```js
// Step 1: Add your middlewares.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


//STEP 2 : Send your JS code to client.
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(`
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var info = {
            clientwidth: 'test',
            clientheight: 'test',
            clientspeed: 'test'
            };
        var objectData = JSON.stringify(info);
        $.post('/', { clientInfo: objectData });
        }
    </script>
    `)

    // Avoid return next() if you've already returned a response.
    //return next()    
});


// Step 3: Get details from the client and analyse it 
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let clientInfo = req.body.clientInfo;
    res.json({ok: true});
    console.log('Client connected: ' + clientInfo);
    
    // If the details from client has been pre-procesed successfully, redirect the client.
    res.redirect('192.168.1.254')
    
    // Avoid return next() if you've already returned a response.
    //return next()   
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, any advice on how to work around - suggested link didn't help

Comment: You can either send the script data, or redirect the user. What I understand from your code is, you also want to make a post call once the user has the script (with the user data). So if sending the user the script is high priority, remove the last get. Add the redirect at the end of the post request. (also remove the return next from post). This way, once the user post's their data and is verified, they are redirected. (This is what I could understand with the existing code).

Comment: Cheers, still the same issue though the http header is closed after the first send. Wish this worked like django so much cleaner :(

Comment: Hey @fmac, Can you update the question by explaining what you're expecting the code to work like? Maybe we could then come up with a solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it - updated it, very simple but it'll remove this hurdle

Comment: Hi @fmac I've tried to edit your code. I hope this solve the issue.

Comment: Same problem Raghav :/ Gonna try a jiggle the code around to see if there's another way around it